# Spacy to store full names

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, spacy

Using spacy to tokenize scraped Tweets. I know we can filter by parts of speech. I'm filtering for proper nouns but it is still breaking up first name and last name as two tokens. I'm going to use these tokens for a network analysis so I'd like to keep proper names together.

This is the code I have now:

```
uniquewords = {}

for tweetzipfile in tweetzipfiles:
  zf = zipfile.ZipFile(tweetzipfile)
  for i, obj in enumerate(zf.infolist()):
    tweetjson = json.load(zf.open(obj))
    tweetText = tweetjson['text']
    if len(tweetText) > 50:
        twetTok = nlp(tweetText)
        keep = ('VERB','NOUN', 'ADJ', 'ADV','PROPN')
        for token in twetTok:
            if token.pos_ in keep:
                word = token.text
                if word.startswith('http') | word.startswith('RT') == False:  
                    if word in uniquewords:
                        uniquewords[word] += 1
                    if word not in uniquewords:
                        uniquewords[word] = 1
```

however for example, a tweet might contain the player Chris Duarte but the dictionary is storing Chris and Duarte separate, instead I'd like to have one dictionary item as ChrisDuarte: 123.

I know spacy can find entities but it doesn't look like full names are a part of that.

Any insight would be awesome.

Comment: Can you give an example of your input text? I think you should be able to get what you want using named entities, you can test spaCy's output in the browser here. https://explosion.ai/demos/displacy-ent?text=Chris%20Duarte%20is%20a%20sports%20professional.&model=en_core_web_sm&ents=person%2Corg%2Cgpe%2Cloc%2Cproduct%2Cnorp%2Cdate%2Cper%2Cmisc

Comment: Check the answer out here... don't be fooled by the question's code not using spacy (the answer does): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58299587/how-can-i-keep-multi-word-names-in-tokenization-together

Answer (score 1):

You can try merging the noun phrases by calling `nlp.add_pipe("merge_noun_chunks")` after you call `nlp = spacy.load()`. However, this will merge all the noun phrases in your data, not only proper nouns. Maybe for your use-case, this will do the trick.